# Rename multiple files in a local folder by a specific order in python

Tags: python, file, split, multiprocessing, rename

i want to rename multiple python files by a specific ordering:

My current output file name is

```
e.g. https___c.tile.opentopomap.org_16_j_i (e.g. https___c.tile.opentopomap.org_16_34309_22369)
```

But the wanted output filenaem should look like this:

```
e.g. https___c.tile.opentopomap.org_16_i_j (e.g. https___c.tile.opentopomap.org_16_22369_34309)
```

I do not see the error in my code so far:

```
import requests
import multiprocessing
import pprint
import time

print("The pictures will be saved all what is east-south from Mannheim Quadrate")
x2 = int(input("North-South (latitude) (start: 22369): "))
x3 = int(input("East-West (longitude) (start: 34309): "))
urls = [
    f"https://c.tile.opentopomap.org/16/{j}/{i}.png" for i in range(22369, x2 + 1) for j in range(34309, x3 + 1)]

def download_image(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    splitted_url = url.split("/")
    last_part = splitted_url[-1].replace(".png", "")
    second_to_the_last = splitted_url[-2]
    splitted_url[-1] = second_to_the_last
    splitted_url[-2] = last_part

    print(f"Downloading from {url}...")
    url = url.replace("/", "_").replace(":", "_")
    with open(f"{url}", "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)

    print(f"Downloading from {url}...")
    url = url.replace("/", "_").replace(":", "_")
    with open(f"{url}", "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter()
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    p.map(download_image, urls)
    p.close()
    stop = time.perf_counter()


    print(f"It took {round(stop - start, 2)} seconds in total")
```

This part should do the job:

```
    splitted_url = url.split("/")
    last_part = splitted_url[-1].replace(".png", "")
    second_to_the_last = splitted_url[-2]
    splitted_url[-1] = second_to_the_last
    splitted_url[-2] = last_part
```

but it does not work. The filename is still in wrong ordering (e.g. https___c.tile.opentopomap.org_16_34309_22369

I do not know why it does not switch the last parts of the file name. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You do: splitted_url = url.split("/") but then later on keep using ‘url’ without having changed it.

Comment: Also, why do you write to the file twice?

Comment: Hi, i addressed your comment and exchanged "url = url.replace("/", "_").replace(":", "_")" with "splitted_url = url.replace("/", "_").replace(":", "_")" but the outcome of the filename is: https___c.tile.opentopomap.org_16_34309_22369 and not https___c.tile.opentopomap.org_16_22369_34309. happy to receive your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to join the `splitted_url` back together again:

```
splitted_url[-1] = second_to_the_last
splitted_url[-2] = last_part
url = '_'.join(splitted_url)    # join the parts together

print(f"Downloading from {url}...")
url = url.replace("/", "_").replace(":", "_")
with open(f"{url}", "wb") as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Hi, it worked by including the line:"url = url+'.png'" to get png as output files! Awesome, thank you

Answer (score 0):

why not just switch i and j?

`urls = [ 
    f"https://c.tile.opentopomap.org/16/{j}/{i}.png" for i in range(22369, x2 + 1) for j in range(34309, x3 + 1)]`

becomes:

`urls = [ f"https://c.tile.opentopomap.org/16/{i}/{j}.png" for i in range(22369, x2 + 1) for j in range(34309, x3 + 1)]`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, the downloading part is correct. If i switch i and j, than the png is wrong. I only need switching the last parts of the filename after downloading for further processing.